# Is $I - A$ a compact operator, where $A$ is a compact operator and $I$ is the identity operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that the identity is not a compact operator in an infinite dimensional space, is the difference composition of the identity operator  with a compact operator a compact one?

Comment: The zero operator is compact, so $A=0$ is a counterexample.

Comment: If $A$ is compact, then $I - A$ cannot be compact.

Comment: Actually, given that the compact operators are a linear subspace $I-A$ can't be compact for any compact operator $A$.

Comment: The intuition is that a compact operator is "small" and the identity (or any operator with infinite-dimensional closed range) is "big".  If you perturb something big by something small, the result is still big.

Answer (score 5):

Identity on a finite dimensional space is compact, so it is best to specify what sort of space you are talking about.

If $1-A$ was a compact operator, then $1-A+A$ would be compact.

Comment: @Kamal Here is discussion on the sum of two compact operators https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011095/possible-flaw-in-proof-that-a-sum-of-two-compact-operators-is-compact